# Change of Domain result in Lost Emails?

Tags: domain, domain-name, a-record, mx-record, dns-zone

Recently we've had quite a few requests where clients are changing their domain
names and want to keep the same email addresses and have the new domain
be the main site. The old domain will then forward to the new one.

What I'm wondering is, what is the best way to approach this? We changed the
name of the site in the various locations of the hosting account to the new name (www.newname.com)
and it changed all appropriate names in the zone file to the new name and seems to
work fine. The old email accounts are now under newname.com.  How do we
set up the zone files(s) so that the oldname.com email goes to the newname.com email?
Telling the domain to forward in domain management doesn't forward the email, just the
website.

Answer (score 2):

What mail system? In an example with Exchange, you can have as many domains as you like pointed to your Exchange server. You setup the recipient policy for each domain, and simply add the desired email address to each users AD profile.

Answer (score 0):

That depends a lot on what you're using for a mail system. So long as they still own the old domain, that is. Most mailers can be configured to redirect mail. bob.smith@olddomain.com is quietly internally redirected to bob.smith@newdomain.com. The exact methods of this are mailer dependent. It can't be done in DNS that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct way to do this is simply use a **DOMAIN ALIAS**

Answer (score 0):

I do this in sendmail by configuring multiple domains to be handled by the relay.

Edit

```
/etc/mail/local-hosts-names
```

and add the domains you wish to handle. For example:

```
# local-host-names - include all aliases for your machine here.
domain.com
otherdomain.com
yetmore.net
```

After making your changes, and presuming DNS is setup properly, restart sendmail.

Note: this means that user@domain is equivalent to user@otherdomain, because `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/aliases` is hit for both for user verification.